# Shortcut keys for moving lines of code not working properly

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a minor problem that bothers me and I could not find any help anywhere.

As you might know, the used shortcuts for moving whole lines quickly is alt + up/down arrows. Weird thing is that I can only move the line upwards. Alt + down arrow does not work. Does anybody know any possible solution to fix this?

Edit: I forgot to mention that this should work in visual studio or vs code, not in E.g. word or Notepad

Comment: Are you asking about any specific tool?

Comment: I don't think that it is a specific tool, it is supposed to be in default settings, as far as I know. Moving lines in Visual Studio works everywhere I try, but my personal pc.

Comment: So is your question about Visual Studio, then?

Comment: Well yes.. I was told at first it should work anywhere, as a universal shortcut, but right after I read your comment, I tried it in Notepad and MS Word and found out that it works only in Visual Studio. Anyways, I still didn't figure out the problem.

Comment: I added `visual-studio` tag.